# Disable query inside lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

It's possible or how to disable a query inside the lambda expression?

For example if I have a check box for each query that can disable if not checked.

*"If I have a check box for `EmployeeNumber` and unchecked it, the query will be disabled or skip."*

```
ViewBag.dataGWUTA = from user in db.ActiveDirectory2.Where(users =>
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmployeeNumber.Contains(search) : users.EmployeeNumber == null) ||
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.SamAccountName.Contains(search) : users.SamAccountName == null) ||
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.GivenName.Contains(search) : users.GivenName == null) ||
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.Surname.Contains(search) : users.Surname == null) ||
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmailAddress.Contains(search) : users.EmailAddress == null) ||
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.Guid.Contains(search) : users.Guid == null) ||
                //Default
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.SID.Contains(search) : users.SID == null))

                                where user.DateCreated >= created && user.DateModified <= modified
                                select user;
```

I try to use `preprocessor directives` but lol it's useless to my check box because you need to define the condition at the top of `using directives`.

For example

```
#define EmployeeNumber
using System;
...
#if EmployeeNumber
                //Disable if not checked
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmployeeNumber.Contains(search) : users.EmployeeNumber == null) ||
#elif SamAccountName
....
```

**Update:**

We can do like this *-"But I don't know what should put in `else(:)`"*

```
(EmployeeNumber.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmployeeNumber.Contains(search) : users.EmployeeNumber == null) : /*What should I put here???*/) ||
```

Comment: `(!checkBox1.Checked || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmployeeNumber.Contains(search) : users.EmployeeNumber == null)) || ...`

Comment: @MadSorcerer It's a `If(?) Else(:)` operator.

Comment: if `checkBox1` is not checked your `bool` `(?:)` will not be executed.

Comment: @MadSorcerer Yup, I want to disable this condition `(?:)` for example `(Checkbox.checked ? (?:) : disable)` do you get what I mean?

Comment: read my suggestion one more time. i use `||` operator, not a `?`

Comment: @MadSorcerer Almost work! the problem is when unchecked it will not  continue to other condition.

Comment: please make sure that all the parenthesis placed correctly

Comment: Yup, it's correct, but thanks to you because you give me Idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, [Mad Sorcerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3909293/mad-sorcerer) answer is

```
(!checkBox1.Checked || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmployeeNumber.Contains(search) : users.EmployeeNumber == null)) || ...
```

But the problem is when the `checkBox.Checked` is unchecked or the condition is true *`(!false) ||..`*
the query will stop or it will not continue to other condition.

But because of his answer I found a solution:

So to allow the condition continue to other condition it must always consider as false.

```
(Bool ? (?:) : false) || ...
```

In this case the condition will always continue.

See my complete solution :

```
ViewBag.dataGWUTA = from user in db.ActiveDirectory2.Where(users =>
            //Disable if not checked
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmployeeNumber.Contains(search) : users.EmployeeNumber == null) : false) ||
            //Disable if not checked
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.SamAccountName.Contains(search) : users.SamAccountName == null) : false) ||
            //Disable if not checked
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.GivenName.Contains(search) : users.GivenName == null) : false) ||
            //Disable if not checked
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.Surname.Contains(search) : users.Surname == null) : false) ||
            //Disable if not checked
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.EmailAddress.Contains(search) : users.EmailAddress == null) : false) ||
            //Disable if not checked
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.Guid.Contains(search) : users.Guid == null) : false) ||
            //Default
            (checkBox1.Checked ? (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? users.SID.Contains(search) : users.SID == null) : false))

                            where user.DateCreated >= created && user.DateModified <= modified
                            select user;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this?

```
var query = from user in db.ActiveDirectory2
                where // base query criteria
                select user;

// Check if EmployeeNumber is checked
if(EmployeeNumber.Checked) {    
    query = from q in query 
    where // clause on employee number
    select q;
}
```

You can continue to construct your linq query filtering on whatever UI settings may be selected.

Comment: If there are multiple employee number checkboxes, you should just construct a list of employee numbers and check if the list count > 0. Then you can use that same list in to filter the query using a Contains

Comment: Ok, let's say `A` and `B` is checked, If we have 20 rows in `QUERY` *(Let's say Column `A` have 5 and Column `B` have 15)*, what will happen is when `A` is executed it will only take 5 rows and store it into `QUERY` so here comes the problem, when `B` is execute it will only look in `QUERY` with 5 rows because `A` filter out the other 15 rows?

Comment: @Leonel consider using the Concat to union your result sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that I sometimes like to do this kind of thing. It's a bit out there, but I like it because I can condense all of the options quite neatly and I can dynamically change the code at run-time too.

So start with some basic values (these emulate the checkboxes and values that you build your queries from):

```
var hasFirstName = true;
var firstName = "Fred";

var hasAgeMinimum = true;
var ageMinimum = 18;
```

Now set up the queries and the conditions for when they apply:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, Func<IQueryable<User>, IQueryable<User>>>()
{
    { () => hasFirstName, users => users.Where(user => user.Name == firstName) },
    { () => hasAgeMinimum, users => users.Where(user => user.Age > ageMinimum) },
};
```

Then it becomes quite easy to build up the final query:

```
var query =
    filters
        .Aggregate(
            db.ActiveDirectory2,
            (q, f) => f.Key() ? f.Value(q) : q);
```

Yes. That's it.

I tested this, before posting, with some basic data and it worked like a treat.